# Running multiple Raspberry pi together

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am part of a project to build a system and one of the requirements is that we must use the raspberry pi.

The issue we are having is that one raspberry pi doesn't have the processing power we need to do what we want. How can I get multiple raspberry pi to work concurrently?

edit
We are trying to use the raspberry pi to create a matrix of infra red beams to detect when people are moving through them.

Comment: Depends on what you need them to do. There are several ways to parallel processing, and none of them is specific to the Raspberry Pi. Edit your question and tell us more about what you need accomplished.

Comment: Try to create pi cluster.

Comment: I may be wrong in my understanding and my guess at how you are doing this but it seems that the Pi should have plenty of power to do that. How are you approaching this and what limit are you hitting?

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry Pi [compute module](http://www.raspberrypi.org/products/compute-module-development-kit/) has 120 GPIO pins. And enough processing power. Also on the raspberry pi [forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/) you are more likely to find an answer.